# converting a hyperlinked pdf \includepdf to black and white

Tags: color, pdf, pdfpages

Most recent scientific articles come with hyperlinks within the document (generally linking citations to the references; e.g. [this file](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10021-013-9689-5.pdf)).  These are often coloured. When including them into a TeX file, the hyperlinks break but the colour denoting the links remain.

Is there a way to include the pdf in black and white?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf{file.pdf}

\end{document}
```

UPDATE: I found a work around for this in the form of "printing" a new PDF in greyscale (Print/advanced/colour - change to Composite Gray). If someone knows of some TeX based method...please do let me know!

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no way of doing this, as per the [`pdfpages` documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages).  However, it does mention how to change the background page color.

The workaround you mentioned is perhaps the easiest way to deal with it: print your document to .pdf (say, with [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator)) in gray-scale and then normally `\includepdf` it.